# With KVM, can you set the hard drive storage to be dynamic/auto-expand with the contents of the guest?

Tags: kvm

Is it possible to have a guest hard drive that grows with usage rather than pre-allocated at the time the guest is created?

I'd like to specify a maximum size or perhaps not specify any size at all at all and have the guest consume as much of the HDD as required.

I imagine within the guest that would be challenging to manage, particularly if the guest formats the hard drive expecting a certain amount of storage (thinking a Windows or MacOS guest)

Answer (score -1):

Not really.

The closest you can come to that is to make your VM boot a kernel over the network (e.g. using PXE, and/or bootp/dhcp) and then mount the rootfs from a "network" file system (e.g. NFSv3 or v4) provided by the VM host system, combined with some sort of quota system.   e.g.

- using [quota](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxquota) - which means running that particular VM as a particular uid and/or gid.
- backing the NFS share with a dedicated ZFS dataset.  ZFS has its own tools for managing quotas (which sets a maximum for that dataset to use from the pool) and reservations (which allocates a minimum amount of disk space reserved for that dataset).  See, e.g. [How to Setup ZFS Quotas and Reservations](https://linuxhint.com/setup-zfs-quotas-reservations/)

There are also various problems and issues with having the root fs and /usr, /var, and other directories mounted over NFS, not least of which is the performance overhead of using a network protocol to access what is actually local storage.  None of these issues are insurmountable, but they  are a PITA to deal with.

Also, it's only really a viable option if the guest is running Linux or some other unix-like OS.

It's much simpler to just use raw files, qcow2 files, disk partitions, LVM volumes, ZFS zvols, or some other block device (or file/whatever emulating a block device) to provide a virtual "disk" to your VMs.  There's a multi-step but well-defined and fairly straight-forward process to increase the size of a VM's "disk":

1. Increase the size of the underlying file, partition, LV, ZVOL, etc.
2. Re-partition the virtual disk so that the extra space is allocated to the partition
3. Resize the filesystem so that it uses all of the new space in the partition

Step 1 differs according to the nature of the underlying storage.  e.g. to increase the size limit of a ZFS zvol, run `zfs set volsize=10G pool/zvol`, `qemu-img` can grow a qcow2 image file, `lvextend` can be used to extend the size of an LV, etc.

Step 2 involves running a partition editing tool such as `fdisk`, `gdisk` `parted`, etc (either inside the VM guest, or you can do it from the host while the VM is shut down).

Step 3 involves using the appropriate tool for whichever file system the partition is formatted with - e.g. `resize2fs` for ext2/3/4, `xfs_grows` for XFS - this is usually easiest to do within the VM guest, but can be done from the host system while the VM is shut down.   BTW, [ntfs-3g](https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/wiki) includes an `ntfsresize` tool to resize NTFS partitions from  Linux.  I don't know if there's something similar for Mac VMs, but you can resize from within the Mac VM using Mac's `diskutil`

Comment: This is wrong. You can use thin qcow images that do the exactly what the OP asked for

Comment: @dyasny no, it's correct.   Step 2 is kind of optional because partitions aren't actually required (though they're a good idea - if only because they usefully protect the boot sectors - even with VM disk images).   Step 1 and Step 3 are both required.  qcow2 images need to be grown (Step 1), and even if they grow automatically, they are formatted with a filesystem.  That filesystem needs to be grown as in step 3.

Comment: The OP asked for a growing disk image, not partition resizing options.

Comment: So?  Sparse files or thin-provisioning of whatever kind (including zfs zvols, which also don't pre-allocate actual space on the host's zpool - and, in fact, can take either more or less actual disk space than the VM sees due to compression and snapshots) don't change the available space seen by the VM.   Give a VM a 10G disk and that's all they'll see until it gets expanded (both the virtual block device AND the filesystem on it), whether some kind of spare allocation is used or not.   The OP showed that they're aware of this by mentioning management of the guest VM's filesystem.

Comment: Looks like the OP is happy with specifying a max size. Did you read the question?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Did you?  The OP is clearly asking about having more space available **within** the VM, not some pedantic crap about sparse files or thin provisioning.

Comment: Pedantic crap? Wow.. nevermind, no point talking to you any further.

Comment: there wasn't any point to begin with because you don't have a clue what you're talking about.

Comment: that just made me laugh out loud, thank you for that.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, and it doesn't matter what OS is running inside the guest. All you need do is provision a sparse qcow2 image. It will start at the size of almost zero, and grow up to the maximum defined. Keep in mind it will grow automatically as the guest OS claims more disk space but it will not shrink as you delete files inside the guest, for that there are procedures that I've described in another question on this site.

PS no space management is required inside the guest in order for the underlying disk image to grow. As the guest OS issues disk block claims qemu will grow the disk in the host.